# Unable to mount network drive in Debian; error is "mount(2) system call failed: No route to host."

Tags: debian, mount, synology

I've installed Debian 12, and I'm wanting to map/mount a network drive (hosted on a Synology NAS).

I see no reason for the 'no route' error as I can ping the Synology server's DNS name and IP address. Both respond just fine.

Furthermore, I also have a separate Ubuntu workstation where this same line in the */etc/fstab* works:

`//myserver.local/mynetworkdrive/ /mnt/mynetworkdrive/ cifs auto,vers=2.0,credentials=/home/myusername/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,noperm 0 0`

Doing a `sudo dmesg` returns this bit of information:

`CIFS: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3.1.1), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3.1.1 (or even SMB3 or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.`

`CIFS: Unable to determine destination address`

However, the solution to this message appears to be already taken care of with the 'vers=2.0' directive I have in the fstab file (I've tried changing the version numbers with no success).

Suggestions for the next steps to help resolve?

Answer (score 3):

After some more research, it turns out I had a few missing packages:

`sudo apt-get install keyutils`

`sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

I needed both in order for the problem to resolve itself.

Hope this helps someone who might have also run into this issue.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils` was enough on Ubuntu 22.04